# Uploading/Downloading word file to/from Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, file-upload

I am in the process of creating an app that allows a user to fill in a from and upload their CV to a potential employer. At the moment I am stuck on uploading the CV to my database.

```
        //File chooser
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\Dawid\\Desktop"));
    fc.setDialogTitle("CV Upload");
    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    /*********************************************/
    //Buttons
    JButton open = new JButton();
    JButton btnBrowse = new JButton("Browse");
    btnBrowse.setBounds(312, 172, 89, 23);
    qualifications.add(btnBrowse);
    btnBrowse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
            if(fc.showOpenDialog(open) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION);
            CvUploadTextField.setText(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
        }
    });
```

This piece of Code sets up my File chooser and prints out the filepath on a text box. What i would hope to achieve is to be able to take the filepath from that textbox and be able to upload that file to the database, in a similar fashion to the below.

```
                 try 
              {
                  Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
                  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
                  Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                  ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM javaapp.test");
                  int val = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO javaapp.test (Name,DOB,Phone,Email,Q1Name,Q1Title,Q2Name,Q2Title,W1Name,W1From,W1To,W2Name,W2From,W2To,About)"
                        + " VALUES ('"+Name+"','"+DOB+"','"+Phone+"','"+Email+"','"+Q1Name+"','"+Q1Title+"','"+Q2Name+"','"+Q2Title+"','"+W1Name+"','"+W1From+"',"
                                + "'"+W1To+"','"+W2Name+"','"+W2From+"','"+W2To+"','"+About+"')");
                  if(val==1)
                      System.out.print("Successfully inserted value");
                  conn.close();
              } 
              catch (Exception e) 
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
```

I know files aren't like strings and integers so I cannot figure out how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) has a method, getSelectedFile(). Which is a File. You can

If you want to allow only .doc, .docx extensions set

```
 JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
        "word docs only", "doc", "docx");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
```

The save it as

```
 File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();

        try {
            String fileName = selectedFile.getCanonicalPath();
            if (!fileName.endsWith(EXTENSION)) {
                selectedFile = new File(fileName + EXTENSION);
            }
            ImageIO.write(image, FORMAT_NAME, selectedFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: This will definitely be useful. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload word files to a database you might want to look up **BLOB** datatype for mysql and also **byte arrays** for java.

**RECOMMENDATION**:
It would be ideal to store files on your SERVER and store the directory path for those files in your database so you know where to look when retrieving them. This would not only be an easy implementation but also wise.

Comment: But if you still insist on uploading the files to your database, I can give you more information on how to.

Comment: I am fairly new to databases so I presume that if you say that putting files on a server is better than on a database than I would probably go around doing it that way, but than again i would have no idea how to go about doing so. Any pointers? I'm currently working on a database set up at home, using a WAMP server.

Comment: Well , it depends on your long terms goals. Lets says if you want to search the files later on based on attributes or want to track changes, keep versions etc then that case DB are much more powerful. The code is last thing to worry design and requirements are, based on what you want to do in long run.

Comment: What i intend to do with it is, When a person applies he/she fills in a form and than attaches a cv to that form. They click submit and send the information to a database. Currently i have the information saving properly and i can view it in app as an admin. What i wish to add is the option to view the cv that was uploaded in the admin window also.